# Python3:Vectorizing 2D function as output for 2D array

Tags: python-3.x, vectorization

I have a simple function:

```
def F(rx,ry):
    return rx**2+ry**2
```

Then I have to fill an array by running this nested loop:

```
for i in range(xarr.size):
     for j in range(yarr.size):

         rx=xarr[i]
         ry=yarr[j]


         array_2d[i,j] = F(rx,ry)
```

Is it possible to vectorize this? My idea is to obtain something like this:

```
 array_2d[:,:] = F(xarr[:],yarr[:])
```

I saw this:

```
 vectfunc = np.vectorize(F,otypes=[np.float],cache=False)
```

This can give me a 1D array, for example:

```
 vectfunc(xarr,1)->1D array
```

But I don't see how this can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, the operations you want to do are already vectorized in `numpy`.

So, if your input arrays are numpy arrays, you can just make a function that does basically this (without the %timeit).  This shows your operation on 2 numpy arrays of length 1M:

```
In [29]: import numpy as np                                                     

In [30]: arr1 = np.random.rand(1_000_000)                                       

In [31]: arr2 = np.random.rand(1_000_000)                                       

In [32]: %timeit result = arr1*arr1 + arr2*arr2                                 
3.54 ms ± 25.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [33]:
```

Comment: What if the function gets more complex? 
This function was an easy example. What if it contains several if's or it calls other functions?

Comment: With creative use of the `np.where` function, you can usually tackle simple `if` operations.  If the fundamental operations are comprised of the things that are already vectorized in numpy, then you will enjoy vectorized performance on numpy arrays, if the subordinate functions also do same.  If not, then you will get non-vectorized performance.